# Expression Engine: Matching Users to Member Groups

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

Hi I am currently writing a few functions for various hooks such as

- [safecracker_submit_entry_end](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/development.html#safecracker-submit-entry-end)
- [entry_submission_ready](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/index.html#entry-submission-ready)

and I need to work out what member group the current user belongs to. So far to get the extension up and running I have been writing IF statements with hard coded ids like so

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
if($this->EE->session->userdata('group_id') == 5){ //do something }
```

Is there a standard way to match users to member groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are making an extension or module, and need a list of available groups to choose from on the settings page, then you can load the member model and use get_member_groups() to get a list.

EE setup installs the default groups as

```
(1) Super Admins
(2) Banned
(3) Guests (visitors)
(4) Pending (registered, but not yet validated)
(5) Members
```

Any other groups you come up with will have a higher ID than 5.
Picking the hard-coded value for 'members', is probably safe.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PHP that is indeed the only way.

You can also access it via an array like this:

`$this->EE->session->userdata['group_id']`